# the filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed codeigniter webp

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload a webp image from website which developed by using CodeIgniter. But I am getting "the filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed" error.

application/config/mimes.php

```
'webp' => array(
    'image/webp'
),
```

in upload function

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|webp|JPEG|JPG|PNG|GIF|WEBP';
$this->upload->initialize($config);
echo "Upload about to start";
if ($this->upload->do_upload("images")) {
 $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's configured okay, perhaps the file isn't actually a WEBP file, and you are running afoul of the check at https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/0648ae2acb3fae84f2cc49e15edb345ccef6cad5/system/libraries/Upload.php#L904 ?

Comment: No file type is webp only.. I only made that image in photoshop.. There is no problem with pic

Comment: It's worth running the same check that CI is running there, basically see what the output of `var_dump(getimagesize('your-file-name.webp'))` is.

Comment: image-type : "image/webp" 
image size : 9958
image name : "1.webp"

Comment: Hmm, okay, that seems all good too. Unfortunately, I don't know what else to explore.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the line:
to the CodeIgniter config file '**mimes.php**'

```
'webp'  =>  array('image/webp'),
```

This will certainly allow the upload of the '**webp**' type;

But **be warned** that any image processing may fail if you have other functions that then handle the 'webp' - like typical image resizing - i.e. :

"Re-sizing -
Image processing failed. Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct."

Also - do not **CAPITALIZE** your '**allowed_types**'!
""

Answer (score 0):

You can add the line: to the `CodeIgniter` config file `mimes.php`

```
'webp'  =>  array('image/webp', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

This will certainly allow the upload of the `webp` type;